# Unable to click bootstrap modal dialog buttons using Poltergeist

Tags: rspec, capybara, poltergeist

When I click on a button, a bootstrap modal popup displays. I tried to click on the OK or cancel button using Poltergeist functions as below, but none worked. Either the functions doesn't work or clicks outside.

```
<div class="modal-footer">
<a class="btn cancel" data-dismiss="modal" href="#">Cancel</a>
<a class="btn proceed btn-primary" href="#">OK</a>
</div>

click_link "Release"
page.driver.render('ReleaseOKCANCEL.jpg', :full =>true)
```

On Clicking 'release', there will be a bootstrap modal with OK and cancel buttons, which can be verified with the screenshots. Trying to click on OK button with the below commands.

1. page.find('.btn.proceed.btn-primary').trigger('click')
2. click_link('OK')
3. page.execute_script('$(".btn.proceed.btn-primary").trigger("click")')
4. page.execute_script('$(".btn.proceed.btn-primary").trigger("hover").trigger("cli‌​ck")')
5. page.all(".//*[@id='confirmation_dialog']/div[3]/a[2]").first.click
6. click_button "OK"
7. click_on "OK"
8. page.dismiss_confirm do page.find('.btn.proceed.btn-primary').click end
9. page.find('.modal').find('.modal-footer').find('.btn.proceed.btn-primary').trigg‌​er('click')

But nothing works. There will be a status change in the application after clicking on OK button. But that doesn't happen.

Comment: 1) page.find('.modal').find('.modal-footer').find('.btn.proceed.btn-primary').trigger('click')
    2) page.find('.btn.proceed.btn-primary').trigger('click')
    3) click_link('OK')  
    4) page.execute_script('$(".btn.proceed.btn-primary").trigger("click")')
    5) page.execute_script('$(".btn.proceed.btn-primary").trigger("hover").trigger("click")')
    6) page.all(".//*[@id='confirmation_dialog']/div[3]/a[2]").first.click
    7) click_button "OK"
    8) click_on "OK"
    9) page.dismiss_confirm do
        page.find('.btn.proceed.btn-primary').click
    end

Comment: Versions - 
    Poltergeist - 1.5.1
    Capybara- 2.4.4
    Ruby - 1.9.3
    
    I'm running via rspec "File name with path"

Comment: and you are sure that you can actually find those elements ? I had similar problem and it turned out that deep down stack of divs the modal was in iframe which is another DOM context (to put it that way)

Comment: Ya visible, I was able to view it through page.driver.render(@screenshotLoc + 'page.jpg', :full =>true)

Comment: thats not what i asked, are you able to reach it via jquery selectors?

Comment: nope, thats the issue . I can't perform any action on the modal with any means

Comment: can you post an html then ? preferably via pastebin or something if its large

Comment: Even If I use Jquery or else thing it passes. Either the test fails or the popup gets closed

Comment: <div class="modal-footer">
<a class="btn cancel" data-dismiss="modal" href="#">Cancel</a>
<a class="btn proceed btn-primary" href="#">OK</a>
</div>

Comment: and what result are you expecting exactly ? i mean how do you know that function didn't work ? btw don't post html in comment - rather put it in your post in code block and in formatted form

Comment: Once the OK button is clicked, status will be changed in the main page. But the issue is status doesn't change since click event not happened.

Comment: and how exactly status is changing ? is there something listening for events ? cause in this html you posted there is nothing significant in href attribute... also it would really help if you'd post more html so i can actually try it on my own

Comment: Event trigger actions happen in database where I don't have access. Also I need this Ok button to be clicked on the Modal popup.

Comment: Sorry but i don't really know anything for now, i have some piece of generic html and little else... Couldn't u provide more informations ?

Comment: Given above the snippet and the issue which i faced

Answer (score 0):

I have been writing a bunch of feature/integration specs the last few weeks - and have been targeting alot of fields and buttons within bootstrap modals (although class names have been changed from the bootstrap defaults).

Here a test that works great for me with a vanilla bootstrap modal:

```
 it "displays edit profile page pre-filled for editing after successful form submission" do
    click_link "List a Property"

    within("form#new_user") do
      fill_in "user[login]", with: user.username
      fill_in "user[password]", with: user.password
      fill_in "user[email]", with: user.email
      fill_in "user[first_name]", with: user.first_name
      fill_in "user[last_name]", with: user.last_name
      fill_in "user[phone_number]", with: user.phone_number
      click_button "List My Properties"
    end

    expect(current_path).to eq account_path(:profile)
    within(".profile-name") { expect(page).to have_content user.username }
    find_field("user[first_name]").value.should eq user.first_name
  end
```

Use of the within( ) method within Capybara usually saves alot of targeting issues that I would otherwise encounter.

I should also note that all tests are js enabled with the following line:

```
describe "User", js: :true do
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've been able to click element on Bootstrap modal is

```
execute_script("document.querySelector('.multiselect__tags').click()")
```

where the element is selected by querySelector